# How can I post the posts with different classes in Wordpress loop?

Tags: wordpress

I have such layout in my HTML file.

**HTML**

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="left title ">
        <!--content1-->
    </div>
    <div class=" middle">
        <!--content2-->
    </div>
    <div class=" right tiles">
       <!--content3-->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="section">
    <div class="left title ">
       <!--content1-->
    </div>
    <div class=" middle">
        <!--content2-->
    </div>
    <div class=" right tiles"
        <!--content3-->
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I use WP loop to repeat the same sequence?
I need that whenever the user wants to publish the posts, and the user has the option(choice) to publish the 3 posts with different classes in one row with `class="section"`. Please, experts in WP help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to just give all the divs within a section the same class and differentiate the styles by using nth-child or nth-of-type css selectors. You could then style each div accordingly. for example:

```
:first-of-type {
//left styles here
}

:nth-of-type(2) {
//middle styles here
}

:last-of-type {
//right styles here
}
```